# Zk included .zul page does not wotk with main controller

Tags: include, annotations, zk

I used tabbox to create tabbed page. And each tab includes another zul page. I have 1 controller applied to main page.

If I add some action to component on included zul page, on controller class  I cant catch it. If I apply controller to my zul then it creates new instance of controller class.

Here is my code.

```
<zk>
    <style src="/resources/css/default.css" />
    <window id="Dealer" class="index"
        apply="com.i2i.prm.controller.IndexController" width="100%"
        height="100%">


        <div class="content" >

            <tabbox id="tb" width="100%" forward="onSelect=onSelect">
                <tabs id="tabs">
                    <tab id="info" label="INFO" />
                    <tab id="create" label="CREATE" />
                    <tab id="edit" label="EDIT" />

                </tabs>
                <tabpanels>
                    <tabpanel id="DealerInfo">
                        <include id="DealerInfoContent" src="View/Dealer/DealerInfo.zul" />
                    </tabpanel>
                    <tabpanel id="DealerCreate">
                        <include id="DealerCreateContent" src="View/Dealer/DealerCreate.zul" />
                    </tabpanel>
                    <tabpanel id="DealerEdit">
                        <include id="DealerEditContent" src="View/Dealer/DealerEdit.zul" />
                    </tabpanel>

                </tabpanels>
            </tabbox>
        </div>
    </window>

</zk>
```

And `dealerEdit.zul`

```
<zk>
<window title="Dealer Edit"  >
    <grid width="100%" sizedByContent="true">
                            <columns>
                                <column label="" />

                            </columns>
                            <rows>
                                <row >
                                    <label value="Name"></label>
                                    <textbox
                                        value="@{DealerController.user.name }">
                                    </textbox>
                                </row>
                                <row>
                                    <label value="Surname"></label>
                                    <textbox
                                        value="@{DealerController.user.surname }" forward="onChange=onASD">
                                    </textbox>
                                </row>
                                <row>
                                    <label value="Address"></label>
                                    <textbox
                                        value="@{DealerController.user.address }">
                                    </textbox>
                                </row>

                            </rows>
                        </grid>
</window>
</zk>
```

This is my controller (`IndexController.java`) class:

```
public class IndexController extends GenericForwardComposer {

    private User user = new User();;
    AnnotateDataBinder binder;
    Tabbox tb;

    @Override
    public void doAfterCompose(Component comp) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.doAfterCompose(comp);
        comp.setAttribute(comp.getId() + "Controller", this);
        binder = new AnnotateDataBinder(comp);

        user.setName("Abdul");
        user.setSurname("Rezzak");
        user.setAddress("Giderken sağda");



        binder.loadAll();
    }

    public IndexController() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public void onDFG(ForwardEvent event){
        System.out.println(this.hashCode());
    }

    public void onASD(ForwardEvent event){
        System.out.println(this.hashCode());
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. remove `<window title="Dealer Edit" >` from your included page (DealerEdit.zul) as it forms its own IdSpace. Don't forget to remove the closing `</window>` tag.
2. change your `onASD` method name to include your `Include` component id i.e. `onASD$DealerEditContent`. It seems Include also form its own IdSpace and forward event does not work across IdSpace

This should work.

UPDATE 1: I just confirmed that `Include` is an IdSpace owner component as it implements IdSpace interface so this is the only workaround in your case.

UPDATE 2: I found one more easier way to deal with forwarding events across different IdSpace which is to use component Path within ZUML file for specifying target component. For example in your case you can specify page id in main.zul page

```
<?page id="main" ?>
```

and while forwarding event in your included page such as DealerEdit.zul page

```
<textbox forward="onChange=//main/Dealer.onASD" />
```

Rest of the code will remain the same.

Reference: http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/Event_Handling/Event_Forwarding#Using_component_Path

Comment: It does not work on my use case. I have the same exact example, without annotations- Must you use the @Listen annotation to make sure it works?

Comment: @daitangio where in my answer I'm using `@Listen` annotation? Also post a new question with your code that produces your issue for us to take a look, thanks.